# One to Many with Cascading not persisting the child entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to do a merge operation on my parent entity it should persist the child entities as well as I using hibernate cascade Save_Update.

here's the mapping

Table name Data :-

```
@OneToMany
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@Column(name="DATA_ID")
private List<Details> details;
```

Table name Details:-

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DATA_ID")
private Data data;
```

merge operation on the Data

```
Session.merge(Data)
```

Please let me know where I going wrong

Comment: did you try CascadeType.MERGE?

Comment: yes, When I change it to MERGE I get Unique Constraint violation error

Comment: which somewhat proves you're heading in the right direction.  Are you sure you don't actually have duplicates in your list?  Can you see that it's persisting at least some of it in your database?  Try using a Set instead of a List for your one to many, I have had nightmare inducing times when I started using Hibernate and used List for my entity collections.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me for persisting BilledProduct objects within a Bill object :

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy="bill", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@HiddenField
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
private Set<BilledProduct> items;



    Customer customer = customerService.findByCustomerNumber("000001");

    Bill bill = new Bill(customer, sequenceService.findNextBillNumberForCustomer(customer));

    HashSet items = new HashSet();

    Product product = productService.findByProductNumber("000001");
    BilledProduct item = new BilledProduct(bill, 2, product, product.getSellPrice());
    items.add(item);

    product = productService.findByProductNumber("000002");
    item = new BilledProduct(bill, 4, product, product.getSellPrice());
    items.add(item);

    bill.setItems(items);
    billService.save(bill);
```

I can update a Bill entity no problem.  Try CascadeType.ALL and orphanRemoval = true, perhaps this has something to do with it.